# How to handle SSL Certificate Expiry for IOT devices connected to the Watson IOT Platform

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-iot

We developed IOT based devices which connects to Watson IOT Platform ; we intend to use SSL Certificates. The devices are based on GPRS and would be installed at remote location. Remote Certificate Updates are not possible.

Now as I read, SSL certificates expire in 3 years. In such case, would the certificate be still valid while communicating with IBM Watson IOT Cloud server.

Currently in our test environment, we are using self-generated certificates and it is working fine.

Can someone share what would actually happen with an expired certificate configured in our devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

most certainty the certificates will stay expired and your device won't be able to reconnect. You would need to renew or replace them in order to stay connected.